How to create a Venn diagram with an OTU-like data frame
I am trying to recreate a Venn diagram with the number different of enzymes found in genome isolated from different sources. The data looks like this:



Genome
Isolation source
AA0
AA1
AA3
AB0




Acetobacter aceti
Plant
0
1
0
2


Acetobacter cerevisae
Ferment
1
1
0
0


Acetobacter pomorum
Fly
2
0
2
1



I would like to do a Venn diagram based on the isolation sources, but I haven't managed.
I tried a couple different things that haven't worked successfully. they produce a plot but somehow most of the groups don't present any enzymes.
-->Isolating the groups and then creating the Venn diagram on it's own:
Insect= colnames(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Insect",             apply(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Insect",], MARGIN=2, function(x) any(x >0))])

Plant = colnames(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Plant", apply(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Plant",], MARGIN=2, function(x) any(x >0))])

Ferment = colnames(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Ferment", apply(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Ferment",], MARGIN=2, function(x) any(x >0))])

Fly = colnames(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Fly", apply(family_profiles_abun_wide[family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation == "Fly",], MARGIN=2, function(x) any(x >0))])

ggVennDiagram(list(Insect, Plant, Ferment, Fly))
-->Removing the genomes and creating the Venn
family_profiles_abun_wide$isolation <- metadata$isolation
family_profiles_abun_wide$bin <- NULL
ggVennDiagram(family_profiles_abun_wide)
##but it gives this error: Error in Venn(x) : All sets should have same classes.
##Could anyone help on what I am doing wrong?
